# After creating a new jhipster project, unable to launch the application

Tags: jhipster

```
After creating a jhipster project, tried with the following command.

**mvnw

    I am getting the following error. For existing project also, i am facing the same issue.
```

Error :
 com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
            at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:111)
            at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56)
            at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$1.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:59)
            at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
            at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.register(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:56)
            at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:815)
            at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:104)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
            at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
            at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not detailed enough but it is obvious that you are using a microservice achitecture and did not start the registry, check [documentation](https://jhipster.github.io/microservices-architecture/).

Comment: Yes, its a Microservice gateway project. I started the registry , and then only tried to launch the application. Yesterday it was not working. But today it got resolved automatically